# where can I find SVG or GeoJSON of countries that uses a 2 or 3 digit country code?

Tags: svg, country-codes, protovis, geojson

I was going to use the Polymaps.org library (combined with Protovis) to create a nice vector based world map.  However, there example (http://polymaps.org/ex/world.html) uses a GeoJSON from Thematic Mapping, but the countries are coded by name instead of by their 2 digit country codes.

When I pair up my data, I have problems with things like "Russia" vs "Republic of Russia".  Anybody know of a GeoJSON file for countries that uses the ISO 2 or 3 digit codes? It seems crazy to use the names.

Any other SVG type file would be useful too.  I could create one, but I feel like it must exist out there and I just don't know how to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not exactly what you want since its not in geoJSON format:

http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/countries.js

Answer (score -3):

May be this is what you want ?  [World Countries Information and ip geocoding  RESTful Web services API](http://www.geognos.com/geo/en/world-countries-API.html)

Happy coding:-)

Comment: no, that is a web service that geocodes an ID.  I am looking for a map layer.